# Why does reinterpret_cast work in some cases but not others?

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast, reinterpret-cast

I just started working with a team that is using `reinterpret_cast` when clearly it should be `dynamic_cast`. Although they are using `reinterpret_cast` the code still seems to work just fine so I decided to leave it alone until recently when it final stopped working.

```cpp
struct Base {
 virtual void do_work() = 0;
};
struct D1 : public Base {
 virtual void do_work();
 std::vector<int> i;
};

struct D2: public D1 { 
 void do_work()
};

struct Holds_data {
    std::vector<int> i;
};
struct Use_data : public Holds_data {
 virtual void do_work();
};


struct A : public Use_data, public Base {
    void do_work();
};

//case 1
// this code works
Base* working = new D2();
D2*   d2_inst = reinterpret_cast<D2*>(working);


//case 2
Base* fail = new A();
A*    A_inst  = reinterpret_cast<A*>(fail); // fails
A*    A_inst  = dynamic_cast<A*>(fail);     // works
```

in case 1 there does not seem to be a problem reinterpret cast SEEMS to work just fine. 
in case 2 i noticed the internal data of std::vector seems to be corrupted when using reinterpret cast

My question is why does case 1 pass? Shouldn't there be data corruption within the std::vector?

Comment: Undefined behavior can do anything. That means sometimes it does what you expected, some times it does crazy things. When UB works as you expected, it's an unfortunate coincidence.

Comment: Clearly the difference is the use of multiple inheritance in the non-working case. But as already said, both are wrong, but you are incorrect to expect an error when all the standard says is undefined behaviour.

Comment: [Almost a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35525057/1460794)

Comment: Rename the second `A_inst` and then print out the addresses of `fail`, `A_inst`, and the other `A_inst `. You'll see something magical. `reinterpret_cast` is a literal reinterpretation of the address. `dynamic_cast`s do something a little bit different and a lot smarter.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` (and even C-style casts) have their place and are *sometimes* (although *rarely*) the right thing to do. *Most of the time* they are *bugs* - like in this case. See also: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub and http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html and https://blog.regehr.org/archives/213

Comment: Some good reading: [When should static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast and reinterpret_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Short Answer

The thing is that `Base* working = new D2();` is implicitly casting `D2*` to `Base*` (`static_cast`).

So if you have:

```
D2* d2 = new D2();
Base* b = d2;
```

You can't be sure that `std::addressof(d2) == std::addressof(b)` will be true. But `reinterpret_cast` is only working if `std::addressof(d2) == std::addressof(b)` is true. So that your code is running correctly is like in the comments mentioned just a fortunate coincidence.

---

### More Detailed

The memory layout for class `D2` could look like:

```
class D2:
0x0000 Attributes of Base
...
0x0010 Attirbutes of D1
...
0x0020 Attributes of D2
...
```

`Base* b = new D2()` will save the address of `Base` (0x0000). Since the attributes of the base classes are always stored before the attributes of the child class, the address stored in `b` (0x0000) is the same as the address returned by `new D2()` (0x0000) and `reinterpret_cast` will work.

But on the other hand the memory layout for class `A` could look like:

```
class A:
0x0000 Attributes of HoldData
...
0x0010 Attributes of UserData
...
0x0020 Attributes of Base
...
0x0030 Attributes of A
...
```

Here the compiler has to store the data of either `UserData` or `Base` first. So if `UserData` gets stored first (like in the example), `Base* b = new A()` will also save the address of `Base` (0x0020), but since `Base` isn't the first stored class in `A`, the address returned by `new A()` (0x0000) does not equals the address saved in `b` (0x0020), since `new A()` (0x0000) was implicitly statically casted to `Base*`. This means `reinterpret_cast` will fail here.

That's why case1 is working and case2 doesn't.

---

One last thing: You should never trust the compiler that it always uses the same memory layout. There are many things concerning the memory layout what is not defined in the standard. **Using `reinterpret_cast` here most likely is undefined behaviour!**